# Deployment of code first project to azure (Multiple projects)

Tags: c#, .net, azure

We are building a solution with 3 projects.

- `MVC`
- `API`
- `DAL`

The DbContext class is located inside the DAL project.
Migrations have been successfully enabled on DAL project.
Everything works fine locally.
When trying to deploy on azure the MVC project the

**Execute Code First Migrations** checkbox is missing.

It seems that somehow our project is not recognized as a code first project (Publishing profile is DbDacFx instead of DbCodeFirst). After trying several solutions we tried creating the projects from the beggining and adding the files one by one checking for the checkbox each time.
The checkbox disappeared after we added a class that inherits from **FlowMetaData** class from Google Analytics SDK.

Is it possible that a third party library could cause such an issue ?

Or maybe something else if forcing Visual Studio (2013) to not show the checkbox ?

Comment: You can always execute the migrations in your start up code, would that solve your problem?

Comment: This is a workaround and not a solution thought. I prefer to solve the problem and figure out what causes this.

Comment: Hi Stefanos - then possibly raise this as a support issue with the Visual Studio team;  searching elsewhere suggests that trying enable-migrations again may fix the issue, others mention something around the dbcontext connection string settings - something in the VS extension is obviously not right to satisfy the conditions for detecting EF code first migrations in your project.

Comment: We tried VS 2013 and 2015 and the issue still remains. Since we tried adding classes one by one, and before the FlowMetaData class the checkbox was there, it seems that adding this class is causing it to disappear.